# applying a promise to getCookies

Tags: javascript

I am trying to apply a promise to getting cookies from the browser

```
browserCookies = {
    art_rfp : '',
    art_token : ''
};


var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.cookies.getAll({"url":"https://url.com"}, function (cookies) {
        for(var i=0; i<cookies.length; i++){
            var name = cookies[i].name
            // console.log(name)
            if (name == 'sso_rfp') {
                console.log(name) // line 13
                browserCookies.art_rfp = cookies[i].value
                resolve('cookies found')
            }
            else if (name == 'sso_token') {
                console.log(name) // line 18
                browserCookies.art_token = cookies[i].value
            }
            else {
                reject('no cookies found')
            }
        }
    });

})

promise.then((message) => {
    console.log(message)
}).catch((message) =>{
    console.log(message)
})
```

However it is just failing.

```
background.js:13 sso_rfp
background.js:18 amzn_sso_token
background.js:32 no cookies found
```

why isn't it resolving?

Comment: Promises don't magically wait for things to complete — there's no way to know how, without solving the halting problem. You can return a promise from within `getCookies()` and resolve it in the `getAll()` callback.

Comment: ok, that's what I was trying, but couldn't get it to work. I've updated my code and put in what's printing. any idea why it isn't resolving?

Comment: Your update uses promises correctly in the technical sense (not sure if business logic wise), but you have a shadowed variable. The object you're trying to assign values to is called `cookies` but the callback parameter is also called `cookies` — you think you're assigning values to the outer object, but you're actually addressing the callback parameter.

Comment: ahhh...shiiiiiiit ok. let me try that

Comment: updated, still not resolving

Comment: Any chance you can put this in a jsfiddle so we can work directly with the code?

Comment: like this? - https://jsfiddle.net/4zu6Lr7f/1/

Comment: A Promise can only be resolved / rejected once!, your using a loop that could potentially resolve or reject at each iteration, that makes no sense.  So when it hits the first reject, that's it, your resolves will no resolve.

Comment: ok, I think I understand. I need it to wait for 1.) the fetch to complete 2.) the for loop to complete, and then check to see if its updated cookies & resolve the promise?

Comment: @MorganAllen  Yes, that's pretty much the idea, I've knocked up an answer with what I think you want..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises can only be rejected / resolved once.

So what's likely happening inside your loop, the first cookie's name is neither `sso_rfp` or `sso_token` as such it will call `reject('no cookies found')`, so even if more are found later, they cannot get resolved because the reject has already been called.

So what you want to do is keep a track using a simple boolean wherever a cookie was found or not found, and then resolve / reject at the end.

eg..

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.cookies.getAll({"url":"https://url.com"}, function (cookies) {
        var found = false;
        for(var i=0; i<cookies.length; i++){
            var name = cookies[i].name
            // console.log(name)
            if (name == 'sso_rfp') {
                console.log(name) // line 13
                browserCookies.art_rfp = cookies[i].value
                found = true;
            }
            else if (name == 'sso_token') {
                console.log(name) // line 18
                browserCookies.art_token = cookies[i].value;
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (found) resolve("Cookies Found");
        else reject("no cookies found");
    });
})
```

Also just a coding standard, I would personally avoid using a global `browserCookies`, and instead resolve with these values instead.